# Check whether data present in array before .push

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I am trying to add data to localStorage, it's a multi-dimensional array.

In order to "append" data to the array, I'm pulling it from localStorage with `.getItem`, using `array.push` to add my new data, and then resetting it with `.setItem`

The array data looks a little like this:

```
var wishlist = [
 ["210 Derby Road","http://localhost:8888/properties/210-derby-grove/"]
]
```

This works fine my only problem is not adding the data twice, so I need to search the array and see if it's present.

I tried first simply using the jQuery utility function:

```
console.log($.inArray(name, wishlist));
```

`name` in this case is `210 Derby Road` so it should return true. This returned `-1` even when the data was present.

I figured maybe because this is a multi-dimensional array that I needed to loop through the sub-arrays instead, so I created a `for` loop:

```
for (var i = 0; i < wishlist.length; i++) {
    console.log($.inArray(name, i));
}
```

I'm still getting `-1` returned.

How can I check my array `wishlist` to see if `name` is present?

## [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0dzpwkrz/1/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You almost got it right! Use:

```
for (var i = 0; i < wishlist.length; i++) {
    console.log($.inArray(name, wishlist[i]));
}
```

cause `wishlist[i]` is the current Array.

Than to get a boolean do like:

```
if($.inArray(name, wishlist[i]) > -1) { /* do something*/ }
```

Comment: Thanks! So close yet so far.

Answer (score 0):

You can do with pure JS method `Array.prototype.includes()`.

```
wishlist.findIndex(f => f.includes(name)) === -1 && // push it.
```